# Reading a CSV with line breaks and nested quotes

Tags: asp.net, csv, c#-4.0

How do you read a csv into c# with line breaks and nested quotes.
At first I was looking for paired quoted to denote a value, but you can have nested quotes!

How is excel able to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel:

- [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Comment: No wonder mine didn't work, I had like 40 lines of code - they have thousands. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this one!

http://www.csvreader.com/